# Minidom - check if tag is present in XML

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, xml-parsing, minidom

I have a script that goes through all the XML files in directory and then parses those XML files to get the data in element `IS` tag `ICP`. However, there are several thousands of those XML files and some of them may not have tag `ICP` in `IS`. Is there a way to do it via minidom?

Example of XML I am parsing that has element `IS` and tag `ICP`:

```
<is ico="0000000000" pcz="1" icp="12345678" icz="12345678" oddel="99">
```

Example of XML I am parsing that has element `IS` but no tag `ICP`:

```
<is ico="000000000">
```

Here my script obviously fails as there is no `ICP`. How to check presence of the `ICP` tag?

My script:

```
import os
from xml.dom import minidom

#for testing purposes
directory = os.getcwd()

print("Zdrojový adresář je: " + directory)
print("Procházím aktuální adresář, hledám XML soubory...")
print("Procházím XML soubory, hledám IČP provádějícího...")

with open ('ICP_all.txt', 'w') as SeznamICP_all:   
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
        for file in files:
            if (file.endswith('.xml')):
                xmldoc = minidom.parse(os.path.join(root, file))
                itemlist = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('is')
                SeznamICP_all.write(itemlist[0].attributes['icp'].value + '\n')

print("Vytvářím list unikátních IČP...")

with open ('ICP_distinct.txt','w') as distinct:
    UnikatniICP = []
    with open ('ICP_all.txt','r') as SeznamICP_all:
        distinct.writelines(set(SeznamICP_all))

input('Pro ukončení stiskni libovolnou klávesu...')
```

I googled a lot, yet I cannot get a simple answer on how to check if a tag is present in XML using minidom.

Could you please give me some advise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`hasAttribute(attributeName)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.html#xml.dom.Element.hasAttribute) method :

```
....
itemlist = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('is')
if itemlist[0].hasAttribute("icp"):
    SeznamICP_all.write(itemlist[0].attributes['icp'].value + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check presence of `icp` by useing `in` operator

```
for item in itemlist:
    if( 'icp' in item.attributes ):
        SeznamICP_all.write(item.attributes['icp'].value + '\n')
        break;
```